# Where has yarn installed my dependency with pnp?

Tags: yarnpkg

I'm using yarn v1 with pnp, configured in the package json with:

```
  "installConfig": {
    "pnp": true
  }
```

How do I find where the code for the dependency is located? Is there something like `yarn debug my-dependency`

Answer (score 1):

When using yarn Plug'n'Play, dependencies are used directly from the yarn cache folder, which is usually at `.yarn/cache/` in your project. To get the exact location, search for the name of your dependency in the generated `.pnp.cjs` file.

Docs:

- https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#packages-are-stored-inside-zip-archives-how-can-i-access-their-files
- https://yarnpkg.com/features/offline-cache